# Swift class not appearing in generated <Project_Name>Swift.h header file

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm having problems importing a class (which is written in Swift and from a pod) into my Objective-C code. I think the problem is due to the class failing to appear in my autogenerated -Swift.h header file, but I don't know how to fix this.

My Podfile has the `use_frameworks!` declaration and I have the pod installed and I'm able to use the pod's class in any of my Swift code but not in Obj-C.

The Swift class I'm trying to import is an extension of UITableViewCell, which is declared as a public class. It didn't have the class declared with the `@objc` annotation in its source but adding it myself didn't seem to make a difference either.

In my Obj-C source I have `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`, (with my actual project name) but my Obj-C file doesn't still doesn't recognise the class after a clean and build. I have checked that the Swift header file exists (and it does) but upon inspection it doesn't seem to have any mention of the Swift class that I'm trying to import.

I tried putting in a forward `@class` declaration to the class in my Obj-C source, but this only removed the warning and delayed the error until I try to build. Modules are enabled in my build settings. If anyone has some insight, your help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
If I manually add the source file to `Build Phases -> Compile Sources` for my project, then everything works - but of course this defeats the purpose of using a pod. So this seems to be an XCode search path issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only public classes and methods are published to be used from other modules. To ensure Objective-C compatibility, you can annotate your classes with `@objc` and inherit `NSObject`.

For example, change your class definition from:

```
class MyClass {
    func sayHello() {}
}
```

To:

```
@objc public class MyClass: NSObject {
    public func sayHello() {}
}
```

---

To use Swift frameworks (iOS 8+) in Objective-C on XCode 7, you just have to import them like you would in Swift using the `@import` statement:

```
@import MyModule;
```

And all your public classes will be available.

---

More information in 'Importing External Frameworks' and 'Using Swift from Objective-C' sections of the [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution. It seems that Swift pods aren't added to the Project-Name-Swift.h, but instead a separate Swift header is generated for each module.

What I needed to do was import the following Swift header file.

`#import "Module_Name/Module_Name-Swift.h"`

An alternate solution that eluded me was pointed out by redent84. You just need to put the following in your Objective-C source as you would in Swift.

`@import Module_Name;`

which is probably equivalent to the swift header import once the sugar is stripped away.